# How to correct the broke flow of a page caused by transform:translateY()?

Tags: css, css-animations, transform

I'm using `transform:translateY()` to move up an element, but the elements below it don't follow the movement; that's ok, I understand that this shouldn't affect the flow of the page, but is there any way to force the below elements to go up along with the element that's receiving `transform`?

I could set `transform` to the other elements as well, but there are a lot of them, so it wouldn't be a very clean solution.

I also thought about wrapping everything in a div and setting `transform` only to the div. It would work. But if there is another way without having to touch the HTML it would be good.

```css
.container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
}

.container div {
  height: 40px;
}

.container div:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
} 

.container div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: green;
  width: 80%;
  
  transform: translateY(-50%)
} 

.container div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: use negative margin-top instead

Comment: Yes, that's good tip. But I was thinking if is there a way to do with `transform: translate`

Comment: no, there is no way for the reason you already explained

Comment: @Temani Afif I see. Thank you! Then I'll go with negative margin .